# After disk reinstallation 2 disks in RAID1 became foreign // PowerEdge r720

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, raid1, hdd

I'm a newbie in DELL servers, so need your advice.

First of all, we have PowerEdge r720 with 4 HDDs, two 2TB SAS with RAID 1 and two SAS 1TB in RAID 1 too.

After the 1 of the HDD was plugged out and plugged in the slot, it's activity LED was no more blinking green. After the server start, half of our VMs were unavailable due to storage connect lost.
We opened a BIOS, where we can see, that the one of the virtual disks is no more available. When we came to Physical disks management page, we've seen that both of 2TB HDDs are became foreign. One of them is in status (Foreign)Online, the other is (Foreign)Rebuild Pending.

Some of the Guides I've read say that after clearing the foreign configuration all data from disks will be erased, others say that the data will not be lost. Who of them are right?

How we can restore those disks without losing data?

If we will use Import Foreign Configuration option, will the other two disks still be working as usual?

Thanks you all in advance!

Comment: Why were you reseating the drive? What is the health status of both drives of the said RAID (to obtain, you can boot Linux from rescue media and issue `smartctl --all -m megaraid,X /dev/sdN`, where sdN is other VD from that controller, and X is the controller-internal number of the physical drive; you can just try integers from 0, they rarely have IDs more than 20. This doesn't correspond to a slot number).

Comment: When dealing with 10+ year old hardware, it's important to minimize these "activities". The attrition rate for hardware goes way up after five years. Exploring a 10 year old server is asking for a failure. Unless you want to test your "backups".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: yes, import a foreign configuration.

---

Recent Dell PERCs are rebranded LSI/Avago/Broadcom MegaRAID SAS controllers, and therefore all LSI techniques and tools apply. To name a few: `megacli` is for configuring anything (creating/removig/reshaping RAIDs, replacing disks, reading logs, updating a firmware of the controller and so on), it's old and obsolete, but it still works, with `storcli` being a modern replacement; `smartctl` can query disks behind a controller even when disks aren't available directly in the OS, but this feature only works with Linux `megaraid_sas` driver to my knowledge. These tools are valuable to monitor the health and maintain the configuration of the controller, arrays and individual drives, doing everyting live, without shutting down an OS and experiencing downtime.

A controller stores configuration both in its NVRAM and on drives. MegaRAID uses SNIA DDF on-disk metadata format, which many other vendors use too, so that RAID could be imported by various RAID controllers of different vendors and even by the Linux kernel software RAID MD driver, if you connect drives to HBA instead of RAID controller.

When you put the drive that contains DDF metadata into a controller and on-drive metadata doesn't correspond to the data in the controller NVRAM, it will mark drive as containing a *foreign* configuration. You can tell controller to adopt that drive, e.g. to copy its configuration into NVRAM, by *importing* a foreign drive.

The drive only contains the information about an array it is member of, not about other arrays of something else about the controller, so import should not have any impact on any other objects in the controller.

To be safe, make backups (isn't that obvious?), as always. It could be worth making an image of one of broken RAID1 members too.

Also, clearing the configuration shouldn't erase data. I once mistakenly deleted a running RAID10 (using `megacli` tool from an OS and mistyped the logical drive number), system failed into kernel panic, because the root file system was located on the deleted LD which disappeared. Later I re-created the array with former disks *without initialization* and the system booted from it as if nothing was happened. It's an initialization process is what actually zeroes a VD.

Comment: Appreciate your help! After the import everything works fine